# Celery task with Scikit-Learn doesn't use more than a single core

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn, celery, python-3.7

I am trying to create a an API endpoint that will start a classification task asynchronously in a Django backend and I want to be able to retrieve the result later on. This is what I have done so far:

`celery.py`

```py
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend.settings")

app = Celery("backend")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace = "CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

`tasks.py`

```py
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def Pipeline(taskId):
  # ...read file, preprocess, train_test_split
  
  clf = GridSearchCV(
      SVC(), paramGrid, cv=5, n_jobs = -1
    )
  clf.fit(XTrain, yTrain)
  
  # ...compute the metrics
```

Django view for executing the task: `views.py`

```py
class TaskExecuteView(APIView):
  def get(self, request, taskId, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      task = TaskModel.objects.get(taskId = taskId)
    except TaskModel.DoesNotExist:
      raise Http404
    else:
      Pipeline.delay(taskId)
      # ... Database updates
```

The problem is the started task only uses one core of the CPU, hence taking a very long time to complete. I also see this error: `Warning: Loky-backed parallel loops cannot be called in a multiprocessing, setting n_jobs=1`. Is there a way to solve this?

I am aware of a similar question on SO made in 2018 that is kind of similar to this, but that post has no definite answer, so I am looking for a solution with no luck so far. Thanks for your time and any suggestions/solutions that you may want to spare, although I don't really want to change the tech stack unless I can avoid it.

What I have tried so far:

Using `threading.current_thread().setName("MainThread")` as the first line in the celery task, but that did not work.

EDIT:
`requirements.txt`

```
amqp==5.0.2
asgiref==3.3.1
billiard==3.6.3.0
celery==5.0.5
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
click-didyoumean==0.0.3
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.1.6
cryptography==3.4.6
defusedxml==0.7.1
dj-rest-auth==2.1.3
Django==3.1.3
django-allauth==0.44.0
django-cors-headers==3.6.0
djangorestframework==3.12.2
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.6.0
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==3.3.0
joblib==1.0.0
kombu==5.0.2
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.19.4
oauthlib==3.1.0
pandas==1.2.0
Pillow==8.0.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.8
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pycparser==2.20
PyJWT==2.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2020.4
redis==3.5.3
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
scikit-learn==0.24.0
scipy==1.6.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
typed-ast==1.4.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.4
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
wrapt==1.11.2
zipp==3.4.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by switching over to `django_rq` ([Github link to the project](https://github.com/rq/django-rq)).

I don't understand the concepts of parallel/distributed computing that much myself, but [the issue was that `celery` tasks do not support multiprocessing inside them](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4551#issuecomment-367607234). So essentially, I can't spawn other processes inside a process that's daemonic.

I don't know how `django_rq` handles this, but I only changed two lines in the code and that solved the issue.

```py
from django_rq import job

@job('default', timeout=3600)  <--- changed here
def Pipeline(taskId):
  # ...read file, preprocess, train_test_split
  
  clf = GridSearchCV(
      SVC(), paramGrid, cv=5, n_jobs = -1
    )
  clf.fit(XTrain, yTrain)
  
  # ...compute the metrics
```

... and rest of the API remained the same.

I will update this answer once I understand the core concepts in parallel computation and why `celery` failed where `django_rq` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will come useful to you. I recently had a problem with the celery worker getting stuck and blocking the line.
The thing is that celery is supposed to automatically spawn as many workers as the server has CPUs, but i found that number not to be enough for the use i was making of it.

I solved the problem adding `--concurrency=10` in the celery execution line in my container commands. You can add this flag manually if you start celery from the CLI.

The complete execution command is this:

`/path/celery -A my_proj worker --loglevel=INFO  --logfile=/var/log/celery.log --concurrency=10`

This spawns 10 workers no matter what.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this but the result remained the same: only one CPU core was being used at a time. I switched to `django_rq` replacing `celery` and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the warning `Loky-backed parallel loops cannot be called in a multiprocessing, setting n_jobs=1.` appeared in a celery task in which I called the `predict` method of a `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor`.

The regressor was trained using `n_jobs>1`, then saved with `joblib.dump` and loaded by `joblib.load` inside of the celery task.

I could get rid of the warning by the `joblib.parallel_config` context manager:

```py
with joblib.parallel_config("threading"):
    pred = model.predict(X)
```